# Authentication from end user to MVC website to Web API service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC website that users log in to from different locations within our company intranet. The windows credentials should be passed through by IE and then authenticated with an ADLDS provider we have set up. This part seems to work fine. However I then need the portal to talk to a Web API REST service behind the scenes, also within the company, but to also authenticate with the users windows credentials. I don't seem to be able to get these.

On the MVC side I have the following in web.config and hosting the MVC website on IIS

```
<authentication mode="Windows" /> 
<identity impersonate="true"/>
<authorization>   
  <deny users="?" /> 
</authorization>
```

On the Web API side I have the following in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

And this is an example REST call that my MVC website makes to the REST service using the RESTSharp library

```
private readonly RestClient _client;

public ApplicationServiceHelper()
{
    var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiBaseUrl"]; 
    _client = new RestClient(url) {Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator()};
}

public IList<CloudConfigValue> GetCloudConfigValues()
{
    var request = new RestRequest("api/cloudconfigvalue", Method.GET) {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
    var response = _client.Execute<List<CloudConfigValue>>(request);

    CheckResponse(response);
    return response.Data ?? new List<CloudConfigValue>();
}
```

If I step through the code and run the REST request, the response that comes back has a status code of Unauthorized. If I look inside the request object and into the attached Credentials, username and password are both blank.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to get this to work?